# filter free hour from javascript time array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have javascript array with a teaching hour of a teacher in a day

```
{
"time": [
  { "start":"10:00","end":"11:00" },
  { "start":"12:00","end":"01:00" },
  { "start":"04:00","end":"06:00" }
]
}
```

I want to find out free hour of from above array between **10 AM to 6PM**

Output array will like this :

```
{
"time": [
  { "start":"09:00","end":"10:00" },
  { "start":"11:00","end":"12:30" },
  { "start":"01:00","end":"04:00" }
]
}
```

please help me out to solve this

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have compared end of one object with the start of next object;

based on their difference I decide whether or not to include it in freetime.

```js
let timeObj =  {
"time": [
  { "start":"10:00","end":"11:00" },
  { "start":"12:00","end":"01:00" },
  { "start":"04:00","end":"06:00" }
]
}

let newObj = {"time" : []}
let timeArr= timeObj["time"];
for(i=0;i<timeArr.length; i++) {
  if(timeArr[i+1] != undefined) {
    if(timeArr[i]["end"] != timeArr[i+1]["start"]) {
      let freetime = {
       "start" : timeArr[i]["end"],
       "end" : timeArr[i+1]["start"]
      }
      newObj["time"].push(freetime);
    }
  }
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```js
var obj = {
  "time": [{
      "start": "10:00",
      "end": "11:00"
    },
    {
      "start": "12:00",
      "end": "01:00"
    },
    {
      "start": "04:00",
      "end": "06:00"
    }
  ]
};
var numConvert = (t) => (t = Number(t.replace(":", ".")), t += t < 10 ? 12 : 0, t);
var output = [];
var output = obj.time.map(s => [numConvert(s.start), numConvert(s.end)])
  .reduce(function(a, b, i, arr) {
    (i < arr.length - 1) ? (a || []).push([b[1], arr[i + 1][0]]): [];
    return a;
  }, []).map(s => ({
    start: s[0],
    end: s[1]
  }));

console.log(output);
```